# Can I increase MongoDB WiredTiger cacheSizeGB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using a server specifically for MongoDB 4.0.5 and as I monitored the memory usage, it's never been more than 40%.

So I'm kind of intimidated to increase WiredTiger cacheSizeGB to increase performance of my reads but I'm not sure since MongoDB implicitly says avoid doing this in it's docs.
I know the reason of that, so that MongoDB can have the rest of the memory for its operations.
But just as I said, it's never been more than 40%.

So what should I do?

Comment: Nothing. Optimize your queries and indices instead. In order to be positively sure that increasing the cache size provides the wanted results, an awesome lot of testing and monitoring has to be done. In a worst case scenario, your *overall* performance might even drop if you fiddle with the internals. Why do you need to improve performance?

Comment: What do you mean by "Why do you need to improve performance"?
every api trys to be faster

Comment: It is a fallacy to assume that "moar ressources" equals "moar performance". If you experience performance problems, you need to positively identify your bottleneck. It is more likely that you use a bad data model and/or unsuitable indices than that the WiredTiger cache interferes.